# ServiceStack custom contract resolver

Tags: json, servicestack, contract, resolver

Is it possible to provide somekind of custom contract resolver to the build-in JsonSerializer?

The response data is formatted as this:

```
{
  "name":"Rob Angelier"
}
```

The property i would like to set is: **Name**

The question is: How can i deserialize from camelcase to pascalcase notation?

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name property with either:

```
string name = JsonObject.Parse(json)["name"];
```

Otherwise you can create a strong-typed class that matches the JSON to deserialize into, e.g:

```
class Contact { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
var contact = json.FromJson<Contact>();
```

In the ServiceStack JSON test suite you can find [multiple different ways](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/GitHubRestTests.cs) to deserialize the same thing.

Comment: I know how to serialize and deserialize. the question is how can we deserialize from a camelcase notation to a pascal notation. We can use a so called custom contract resolver inside the JSON.net library but is this also possible with the ServiceStack serializer?

Comment: Here some more information about what i'm looking for: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ContractResolver.html

Comment: Deserializing is case-insensitive so you can de-serialize between Pascal/camelCase and vice-versa. `JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;` emits, camelCase properties :) e.g: https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/AppHost.cs#L94

Comment: That's what i'm looking for. I will give it try and mark this as the answer if everything works just fine!